# Turning MSI GS40 without pressing power button

Tags: power

I'm having problem with the power button, and trying to turn on the computer with some other methods.
My computer is MSI GS40QE.
I've tried to turn on the computer with usb keyboard which has power button, however I couldn't find BIOS configuration which allows it.
Please let me know any other method to turn on my computer!

Answer (score 0):

Configure AC Recovery to **Always Power On** in your BIOS, then use a power strip switch to start your PC.

Most BIOSes offer a setting called *AC Recovery* that configures the computer's power behavior when AC power is connected (e.g. via the power cord being unplugged then reconnected). With this set to *Always Power On*, you can start the computer from off state by momentarily cutting the AC power to the PC, then reapply it. The PC will then turn on despite the non-operating power button.